# Rails render HTML also download CSV file in same action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, csv

I have a users controller with index action which has ransack search. My requirement is that I have a form in the UI using which the user searches and the result should display in HTMl as well as I want to download this as a CSV file.

users_controller.rb

```
  def index
    users = User.includes(:client).filter_by(filter_params).order(updated_at: :desc)
    @search = users.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @search.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @users.to_csv, filename: "users-#{Date.today}.csv" }
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
 <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px">
  <%= search_form_for @search, :url => admin_users_url , :builder => SimpleForm::FormBuilder, html: { novalidate: "novalidate"} do |f| %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= f.input :id_eq, :placeholder => "contains", :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', label: "ID" %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= f.input :name_cont, :placeholder => "contains", :item_wrapper_class => 'inline', label: "Name" %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 24px">
        <%= f.submit "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Export Results to CSV", admin_users_path(params.merge(format: "csv")), :class => "btn btn-info" %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

I am aware that one of the two formats render can happen. I want the search results to be exported in a CSV as well. What is the correct way of doing this...

The problem is 'Export to CSV' works as a separate button and the search form fields don't have any connection with this button. How can I export search form results to a CSV?

Comment: You have the correct way of doing it already. I'm assuming the `to_csv` method is defined as a class method in the User model

Comment: Are you trying to generate both HTML and CSV simultaneously?

Comment: No, as a sequential action. I search, the results appear in HTML and I want to export them as CSV.

Comment: Sure. When clicking on Search Button - http://localhost:3002/some_service/admin/users and when clicking on Export Results to CSV - http://localhost:3002/core_service/admin/users. Both looks the same

Comment: @SuganyaSelvarajan you can pass your filter params to the export csv action and this should return you filtered results in csv

Answer (score 0):

Just use javascript to create an event handler that sets request format and submits the form when the users clicks the "Export Results to CSV" button.

```js
document.getElementById('to_csv')
        .addEventListener('click', function(e){
           var form = e.target.form;
           e.preventDefault();
           form.action += '.csv'; 
           form.submit();
        });
```

```html
<form action="/foo/bar">
  <button id="to_csv">Export Results to CSV</button>
</form>
```